# Spring+JPA, campo transient visível na View e que nao seja persistente?

Tags: java, mysql, spring, view, model

Boa noite pessoal, tenho um filtro que faço manualmente com a @query()
que nela eu faço um join calculando total de uma venda ou seja,

```
SUM(valor * quantidade) as total
```

la no fim vou por o filtro pra vcs...
o que ocorre é o seguinte, esse campo "temporario" total que se refere ao total da venda, quando eu crio ele na minha entity o jpa quer persisti ele no banco, daí eu utilizo o @transient porém ele nao fica visível na view, eu teria que da um setTotal() no controller pra poder ele ter algum valor...

ja tentei de diversas formas, segue abaixo....

```
@NumberFormat(pattern = "#,##0.00")
transient BigDecimal total;
```

Desse forma acima, ele não é visível na view, não trás o valor do banco, somente se eu der um setTotal().

```
@Column(updatable = false, insertable = false) // até assim (não funciona)
@NumberFormat(pattern = "#,##0.00")
@Transient
private BigDecimal valortemporario;
```

desas forma acima, ele é visível na view, mas tenta persistir no banco, logico que dá erro, pois o campo não existe na tabela.

```
@Column(updatable = false, insertable = false) // até assim (não funciona)
@NumberFormat(pattern = "#,##0.00")
private BigDecimal valortemporario;
```

Dessa forma acima, também não funciona, ele tenta gravar no banco tbm..

abaixo deixo meu Repository so pra ver ter noção geral da coisa:

```
public interface AtendimentosRepository extends JpaRepository<Atendimentos, Long> {

String sqlPrincipal = "SELECT id_heados, pecastotal.total as total, "
        +" maoobra_heados,+"veiculo_km_heados,bsextras_heados,"
        +" tipoatendimento_heados,  "
        + " datasaida_heados FROM heados  "

        + " LEFT JOIN ( (SELECT pedos.controle_pedos,adicional_pedos,"
        + " sum( ( COALESCE(valor_pedos,'0') * COALESCE(quantidade_pedos,'0') ) - (  "
        + " ( COALESCE(valor_pedos,'0') * COALESCE(quantidade_pedos,'0') )  * COALESCE(desconto_pedos,'0') /100"
        + " ) ) as total FROM pedos as pedos  WHERE adicional_pedos  = 'N'"
        + " group by pedos.controle_pedos) ) pecastotal ON controle_pedos  = id_heados"

        + " WHERE id_heados = :controle ";

@Query(value = sqlPrincipal, nativeQuery = true)
public Atendimentos atendimentoByControle(@Param("controle") Long controle);
```

}

Tentei encontrar uma forma de retirar da minha classe Entity o campo referente
ao total, mas não encontrei nenhuma função pra isso.

Alguém já passou por isso?? tem outra solução??

Obrigado!!

Comment: A anotação `@Transient` que você está usando é do pacote `javax.persistence.Transient`? Um erro bastante comum é usar a anotação do pacote `org.springframework.data.annotation` que faz algo bem diferente (veja [essa resposta no SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42753469/664577))

Comment: Opa, valeu por responder, já utilizei os dois pacotes nenhum funciona!

Comment: org.springframework.data.annotation.Transient 
Nesse, me deixa visualizar mas tenta persistir no banco.

@javax.persistence.Transient
Esse nao persiste porém vem nulo, nao preenche vindo do banco, eu teria que da um atendimeno.setTotal() no controller mas nao vai dá pois no caso de erro, eu redireciono passando um model, e nesse redirecionamento eu perco as médodos da entity.

Comment: Renato agora entendi melhor o problema. Talvez trazer o resultado da consulta para um POJO externo ao invés da sua Entidade seja a melhor solução no seu caso. Algo como [SqlResultSetMapping](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/SqlResultSetMapping.html) talvez venha a calhar.

Comment: Opa @AnthonyAccioly , como nao utilizei ainda o SqlresultSetmappging fui da uma olhada, mas ainda nao percebi como pode me ajudar, mas vou pesquisar ainda melhor sobre o mesmo, mas fico ainda pensando como nao pode ter uma saída mais simples... so preciso nao persistir esse campo, na verdade ele ja deveria saber que esse campo é criando em tempo de execução, somente no momento do filtro da venda com o JOIN->SUM().... to travado nisso fazem dias, de qq forma Obg!!

Comment: @AnthonyAccioly fiz praticamente uma gambiarra, mas ta funcionando, desacoplei a entity "filha" da entity "pai" ou seja comentei o trecho de OneToMany e ManyToOne , e no controller instanciei a entity "filha" filtrando pelo numero da venda e após isso dei um 
for (PesquisaPecasAtendimento obj : pecasAtend)  totalizando a venda e depois um setValorTotal() , enviando para a view. 
no fim das contas quase q da no mesmo, tirando o FOR e o setValorTotal() que tive q fazer manualmente, fora isso oacesso ao banco dedados de qq forma o JPA faria qndo utilizo o ManyToOne. Obg